# How to edit a toolbar in Interface Builder (Xcode 5)?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, interface-builder, nstoolbar

I have a toolbar in an `NSWindow` in my Cocoa app, and it works great, but I'm having trouble editing it.  When I open it (or double-click on any of its items in the tree on the left in Xcode), the toolbar editing sheet hides behind other views in the `NSWindow`.

Is there a way to edit a toolbar by itself in a new window or something?  Is there a trick to getting other views in my `NSWindow` to go "below" the toolbar in IB?  The toolbar itself is perfectly fine when my program is running.  It's just editing it that's a giant pain.

**EDIT**: Here, the content area of the window has a vertical `NSSplitView`, and the left half (an `NSScrollView`) is completely over the toolbar customizing sheet in IB, and the Custom View on the right side is over the sheet as well but it's transparent so I can see through it a little bit:

[image]

If I delete the window contents (the `NSSplitView`), then I can edit the toolbar (like Jay's picture), but that can't be what I'm expected to do every time I want to edit a toolbar item.

Comment: Should work w/o an issue. Can you link a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

Basically editing the toolbar in IB is as easy as double-clicking..

[image]

Double-click on either the Toolbar or an Toolbar Item and the Toolbar Editor will open in the Editor area of IB. This is the same view users can see when customizing toolbars at runtime.

[image]

To change the toolbar configuration you then change the **Default toolbar items** area to whatever you desire and hit *Done* afterwards!

Comment: Right, that's what it looks like in all the tutorials, but for some reason Xcode decided to always put the sheet *behind* the window contents in IB for me.  How do I bring the toolbar editing sheet back to the front?

Comment: Have you tried restarting Xcode, clean the build folder, deleting the derived data entirely?

Comment: I've restarted Xcode many times, with no improvement, but I'll have to read up on the "derived data" folder.  I know *of* it, but it's not an area with which I'm terribly familiar, and I don't want to wipe out something without knowing what I'm wiping out.

Comment: It's generated data with some settings like open files. Nothing to be damaged there. Go to '*Organizer*' (Cmd-Shift-2) and select your project. There it'll allow you to delete the Derived Data from within Xcode. Just give it a go.

Comment: Nope, clearing out the Derived Data for this application fixed my autocomplete issues, but the toolbar editing is still the same.